# javascript not recognizing special characters

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters, code-snippets

I am implementing a javascript code which makes hashtag linkable as follows -

```
str2 = str.replace(/(^|\s)#([A-Za-z0-9é_ü]+)/gi, '$1<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/$2" class="msfb-wall-auto-link" target="_blank">#$2</a>');
```

if you see i included special hungarian characters like é , ü ... to be included in the hashtag linking but above code break at those special hungarian chars. But when i test that in w3schools.com example code editor things work there. So in my local script file those special chars are not being recognized as a character(é) but look like it's being treated as "e" character. Why this is happening ? how to overcome this problems, please suggest ideas.

Comment: I'm [not able to replicate](https://jsfiddle.net/z9L5nzp1/) what you appear to be saying, can you reproduce the issue anywhere we can see, ideally as a [stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes) and [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#regex). Javascript has some problems with Unicode in regexp.

If you want to match every Unicode letter, you should use this regexp `[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]`.

So your code should look like this:

```
str2 = str.replace(/(^|\s)#([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+)/gi, '$1<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/$2" class="msfb-wall-auto-link" target="_blank">#$2</a>');
```

```js
var str2 = 'abc #łążaf3234 efg'.replace(/(^|\s)#([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+)/gi, '$1<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/$2" class="msfb-wall-auto-link" target="_blank">#$2</a>'); 

alert(str2);
```

Comment: Can you guys plz add examples in my code?? having prob in understanding.

Comment: Look like your code working but links you provided i am not getting till now. Does your regexp code also counts those characters which i mentioned in my code(A-Za-z0-9_). 
Are there any disadvantages can occur ??

Comment: There? please answer my question above

Comment: @dev-m you need to add `0-9` and `_` to the above regex. I've only shown you how to match every unicode letter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to list the special characters [A-Za-z0-9éüíóþæöÉÚÍÓÞÆÖ] (these are icelandic characters) or you could use \S to match any non-whitespace character

Comment: Can you guys plz add examples in my code?? having prob in understanding.

Comment: I dont think the "é_ü" works in regex, you have to list every special char in the hungarian  alphabet [a-z0-9áéëéíóöúü] 
the "i" in "/ig" makes this in-case-sensitive so you don't have to have the uppercase version.
This works for icelandic at least,

Comment: Even if i include all Hungarian alphabets the behavior is same as i mentioned in my code

Comment: Make sure you save your file with utf-8 or unicode encoding

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to use unicode escape sequences (like **\u2665**) rather than the binary character.

Comment: Explain to me why this is wrong.  His regex works typed into an online form, but if he saves his script into a local file, the wide-characters get mangled into 8-bit characters.  Using unicode escapes like  \uXXXX is the solution.

Comment: You mean like \u2665 ??